# How can i write in javascript three numbers in descending order using just `if ...else` statements?

Tags: javascript

I also can't use logical operators but can use comparison operators. Any help would be appreciated.

why is this code not working like i want it to. It seems to work when `a` is the largest but when any other variable is larger it doesn't run. I think it has something to do with my nesting.

```js
var a = prompt("enter a number");
var b = prompt("enter a different number");
var c = prompt("enter another number");

if (a < b) {
  if (a < c) {
    if (b < c) {
      console.log(a, b, c);
    } else if (a > b) {
      if (a > c) {
        if (b > c) {
          console.log(a, b, c);
        } else if (b > a) {
          if (b > c) {
            if (a > c) {
              console.log(b, a, c);
            } else if (b > a) {
              if (b > c) {
                if (c > a) {
                  console.log(b, c, a);
                } else if (a > b) {
                  if (a > c) {
                    if (c > b) {
                      console.log(a, c, b);
                    } else if (c > a) {
                      if (c > b) {
                        if (a > b) {
                          console.log(c, a, b);
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: sounds like a homework question... Try a recursive function

Comment: Work on your nesting. All of your code is inside your first if block. What happens when the first check returns false? The rest of your code is ignored because it's nested inside the if.

Comment: I edited your question to fix the indenting in your code (changing nothing but white-space). It should now be pretty obvious why the code doesn't work if a >= b or a >= c.

Comment: Play computer. Get a pencil and paper and trace the execution of your code how it's actually written, not how you think it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What you did wrong**

- what happens at the beginning if `a < b` is not `true`. Right now your code can't handle cases where `a >= b`.
- same thing for the second `if`: you can't handle cases where `a >= c` so your code only works when `a < b && a < c` (`a` is the smallest number)
- **EDIT:** as pointed out by ***@nnnnnnn***: use `Number(prompt(message))` to get an actual number from the string returned by `prompt`

---

**What to do?**

Add `else` statements to the described `if`s to account for the cases you missed.

---

**Working solution**

```js
// test case
//let a = 2, b = 3, c = 1;

let a = Number(prompt('a')), b = Number(prompt('b')), c = Number(prompt('c'));

if(a > b){
 // c? a c? b c?
 if(a > c){
  // a c? b c?
  if(b > c){
   // a b c
   console.log(a, b, c);
  } 1else {
   // a c b
   console.log(a, c, b);
  }
 } else {
  // c a b
  console.log(c, a, b);
 }
} else {
 // c? b c? a c?
 if(b > c){
  // b c? a c?
  if(a > c){
   // b a c
   console.log(b, a, c);
  } else {
   // b c a
   console.log(b, c, a);
  }
 } else {
  // c b a
  console.log(c, b, a);
 }
}
```

Comment: something still doesn't run right with this code when i give  variable b the larger value and variable a the second largest they don't print out in descending order

Comment: @Oscar my test case with `a = 2, b = 3, c = 1` works fine in Safari TP.

Comment: Why do his homework for him? Instead of spoon-feeding, teach how to solve problems like this.

Comment: @DaveNewton good point. I'll edit my answer to point out his mistakes and how to solve them.

Comment: does javascript see numbers with zeros differently because when i put 500, 1000, 200? The order doesn't show up as descending. Is this because it ignores the zeros. When i put numbers with no trailing zeros it works like expected.

Comment: @Oscar - you are comparing strings, not numbers, because `prompt()` returns a string. If you want a numeric comparison you have to convert the strings to numbers.